# I cannot place blocks in Minecraft PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My game is completely fine, but when I try to place a block down it won't work. I have tried everything but nothing works.

Comment: Are you unable to destroy blocks, or only unable to place them? What's the "everything" that you've tried? Any mods?

Answer (score -2):

The question isn't really clear so if you could provide more details it would be better however I think a normal fix would be tor restart your computer and plus please check in which gamemode you are because in gamemode 2 (adventure) you cant place or break blocks therefore if so change your gamemode to survival. Sorry I forgot to include a small detail that this question has been asked before so please check it out here in this thread [I can't place any blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260380/i-cant-place-any-blocks)

Comment: why would you - rate the answer ???

Comment: Because you're not answering the question.

Comment: @Frank tho, which question? :)

Comment: Frank just don't man this question wasn't even eligible tbh